# Combine two UPDATE statements in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

is there a way to combine the following two statements so that I only write UPDATE table once ? The name of the table is STAT_SEP.

```
UPDATE STAT_SEP LEFT JOIN calendar on STAT_SEP.`Period` = calendar.`Unique_Period`
SET
STAT_SEP.First_Date = calendar.First_Date;

UPDATE STAT_SEP
, (SELECT First_Date AS earliest_date FROM STAT_SEP ORDER BY First_Date ASC LIMIT 1) fancy_alias
SET `Index` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, earliest_date, First_Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate the earliest date in a subquery and then use that for the update:

```
UPDATE STAT_SEP s LEFT JOIN
       Calendar c
       ON s.`Period` = c.`Unique_Period` CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT MIN(c2.First_Date) as earliest_date
        FROM STAT_SEP s2 JOIN
             Calendar c2
             ON s2.Period = c.unique_period
       ) c2
    SET s.First_Date = c.First_Date,
        s.Index = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, c2.earliest_date, c.First_Date);
```

Comment: @fordonLinoff I am getting the following error ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET s.First_Date = c.First_Date, s.`Index` = TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, c2.ear' at line 9

Comment: @bp123 . . . That should be a `CROSS JOIN`, not a `LEFT JOIN`.